# How to check if there is an arc within a polygon (algorithm in geometry)

Tags: polygon, geometry, algorithm

Now I have a polygon with arc like this:
[image]

I need to check if this polygon contains arc or not. How can I do that using geometry?

Clarification about the reason why:
I need to know how to detect in "geometry prespective" if there is an arc within a polygon or not ?

Comment: What do you mean by arc? Kindly elaborate your objectives.

Comment: @PadmanabhaChowdhury The arc is a connected subset of a differentiable curve like the attached image above on the post

Comment: What you want to achieve is still not clear. What is the context of the existence of arc in a polygon?

Comment: @Padmanabha I edited the post with clarifying

Comment: There isn't just one kind of polygon, or even of one CAD format where arc segments are permitted. This makes it crucially important to specify the **exact** data format and **exact** GIS tool in use.

Comment: @Vince the data format is originally dwg and I converted it to dxf format and want to convert it to geojson

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to contain your clarifications. Then it can be reviewed for reopening.